# Map single controller to multiple methods/action

Tags: grails, groovy

My Controller name is ...Login...
and method/action names like....HomeContent.....automotive...etc

I am also posting my controller code here..

```
class LoginController {
    def dataSource;

    static allowedMethod = [userLogin:"POST",HomeContent:"GET",Disclaimer:"GET",FAQ:"GET",OurTeam:"GET",ourPortfolio:"GET",privacyPolicy:"GET",beautyTips:"GET",dietNutrition:"GET",healthFitness:"GET",yoga:"GET",mentalStress:"GET",automotive:"GET",digitalMarketing:"GET",ecommerce:"GET",education:"GET",finance:"GET",foodAndBeverage:"GET",marketUpdates:"GET",realState:"GET",coWorkingSpaces:"GET",homeRemodeling:"GET",scienceAndTechnology:"GET",sportsMania:"GET",travelAndTourism:"GET",boxOffice:"GET",dayToDayNewsUpdates:"GET",mediaGossip:"GET",poertyZone:"GET",lifestyleMagazine:"GET",becomeAContributor:"GET"]


    def HomeContent()
{
    def query ="SELECT  id,post_title,post_date,post_content FROM wp_posts where post_status='publish' and post_type='post' ORDER BY post_date  DESC limit 10"

        def db = new Sql(dataSource)
        def json = db.rows(query)
        render json as JSON
}



    // About Us section starts here         
      def Disclaimer()
    {

        def query = "select distinct id,post_title,post_date,post_content from wp_posts where post_title='disclaimer' and post_status='publish'"

        def db = new Sql(dataSource)
        def json = db.rows(query)
        render json as JSON
    }

     def FAQ()
     {
         def query = "select distinct id,post_title,post_date,post_content from wp_posts where post_title='FAQ' and post_status='publish'"

        def db = new Sql(dataSource)
        def json = db.rows(query)
        render json as JSON
     }
```

and my URLMapping code here..

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

      "/Login"(controller:"Login",action:"HomeContent")


        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: hi abdul...actully i am writing api for my android app.....locally it is working fine..but when i published it to server..then it is not working...it gives an error like resource not found....then i have read something about UrlMappings...then i edited my UrlMappings class which is posted above....it is giving me output but of single method...

Comment: .but i have multiple methods inside my controller ....so i want to map..my controller "Login" to multiple methods...like HomeContnet...automotive.....and i want to form api URL like this..../Login/HomeContent....that give me output of HomeContent method....and when i change URL to ..../Login/automotive...then it give me output of automotive method.....which is also defined in Login controller...

Answer (score 0):

Add generic support to UrlMappings, assuming that's all you want:

```
//inside static mappings:

"/$controller/$action?"{ }
```